# Charts3.0 - Can not show all the xAxis label if more than 8 value - Swift

Tags: swift, charts

I had create a bar chart which had the 9 categories label for the xAxis:
["Foods", "House Loan", "Insurance", "Petrol", "Saving", "Train", "Others", "Books & Magazine", "Car park"]

But in the charts it just show:
Foods, Insurance, Saving, Others and Car park

Any one know how to solve it?

Here the source code for setting xAxis

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {       
     var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

     for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

         let value = values[i] as Double
         let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y:value)
         dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
     }

     let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Total Amount")

     var colors: [UIColor] = []
     for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
         let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
         let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
         let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

         let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
         colors.append(color)
     }

     chartDataSet.colors = colors
     chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
     barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""

     barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
     barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
     barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
     barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
     barChartView.xAxis.decimals = 0

     let chartData = BarChartData()
     chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
     barChartView.data = chartData
     barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self

     let format = NumberFormatter()
     format.numberStyle = .decimal
     let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)
     chartData.setValueFormatter(formatter)
     barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: TimeInterval(1))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to set the label count.
barChartView.xAxis.labelCount = dataPoints.count